# CDO 4.17 and Java 11

Tags: java, eclipse

Does anybody know which Java version I need to use with Eclipse CDO 4.17? I can't find any information on its official page. Currently I'm using CDO 3.0 and Java 6 and I'm going to upgrade my tools and I try to understand minimum requirements for CDO 4.17 - Java, Eclipse, EMF, etc.

Also, I tried to find differences between CDO versions and its vulnerabilities but I found nothing. If anyone knows something about it, please share it with me.

I just try to understand the best versions of CDO, Java, etc for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this page](https://www.eclipse.org/cdo/downloads/versions.php?sr=4.17) CDO 4.17 is based on 4.22 and EMF 2.28. It is part of the simrel (simultaneous release) 2021-12.

For that release [Eclipse says](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#Eclipse_4.22_.282021-12.29):

> A Java 11 or newer JRE/JDK is required, LTS release are preferred to run all Eclipse 2021-12 packages based on Eclipse 4.22, with certain packages choosing to provide one by default.